# How do I conditionally send a body param in my curl request

Tags: bash, curl

I  am creating a simple bash script. I have this curl request, and I only want to send `objects_count` in my raw data body if it is non empty.

I know that this line of code works:
`'[ ! -z "$objects_count" ] && echo "not empty"'`

However when I implement it in my curl request, I get an error

```
    objects='[]'
    objects_count=''

    curl --location --request POST 'http://0.0.0.0:5000' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '{
        "objects":'$objects',
        '[ ! -z "$objects_count" ] && "objects_count":$objects_count'
    }'
```

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
]
 ^
```

Comment: Don't create JSON using string concatenation, use the `jq` tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't have a conditional operator that can be used in expressions. Use a simple `if` statement to set a variable to the data you want to send.

```
if [ -z "$objects_count" ]
then
    data='{"objects":'$objects'}'
else
    data='{"objects":'$objects', "objects_count":'$objects_count'}'
fi

curl --location --request POST 'http://0.0.0.0:5000' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw "$data"
```

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be reversed?

Comment: Thanks, but is there a workaround that doesn't use a simple if statement. I have more body params than objects and objects_count. Though, I am currently looking into jq to build the json body.

Comment: There's probably some way to do it with `jq`, but I don't have much expertise with it.

Comment: Do you have to do this in bash? It's much easier in PHP or Python.

Comment: @Barmar I don't have to do this in bash. I just thought that sending curl requests through a bash script would be easy.

Comment: It is, but creating dynamic content is harder.

Comment: Realizing that now lol.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use expressions like that in the middle of an expression. If you really want an expression you need a subshell, and inside the subshell `echo` the string you want:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://0.0.0.0:5000' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "objects":'$objects',
    '$([ ! -z "$objects_count" ] && echo '"objects_count":'$objects_count)'
}'
```

However, there's a trick using parameter substitution where you can expand a string only of a variable isn't null (or unset):

```
echo ${objects_count:+non empty}
```

Then you don't need an expression:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://0.0.0.0:5000' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "objects":'$objects',
    '${objects_count:+'"objects_count":'$objects_count}'
}'
```

I don't see why you would need to selectively output this element though, in JSON you can typically just do `"object_counts": null` or something like that.

BTW, instead of doing `[ ! -z "$foo" ]` you can just do `[ -n $foo ]`.